# Expanding symbol variable inside a macro

Tags: crystal-lang

```
class Controller
  def index
    puts "hello"
  end
end

macro handler(controller, action)
  c = {{controller}}.new
  c.{{action.id}}
end

# this doesn't work
temp = :index
handler Controller, temp

# this works
handler Controller, :index
```

Somehow on the first case, the macro gets expanded to `c.temp` instead of `c.index`

Is it possible to call a function inside a class like in above code snippet.

Edit:
I am trying to achieve something like this, https://github.com/Amber-Crystal/amber/blob/master/src/amber/dsl/router.cr#L16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` is a runtime variable, while macros are interpreted at compile time. That means the Crystal compiler can't actually know the value of `temp`, as it is only known at runtime. Tracing variables to literal values could be done to some degree, but would be expensive and brittle to use, since a small change may make it impossible.

When you call a macro, the arguments are actual AST nodes, expressions of parsed source code. So in your example the macro gets a [`TypeNode`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.22.0/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html) as first argument and a [`Var`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.22.0/Crystal/Macros/Var.html) as second argument.

Comment: Is there a way to call a function in a class by name during runtime? I have checked the docs, I can only do responds_to? to check if a function exists.

Comment: No, you can't. The usual workaround for this is to generate a case when dispatch by collecting for example method names in an ArrayLiteral assigned to a constant, and then iterating that in a macro.